# How to uninstall the .NET German Language Pack in Windows 7?

Tags: .net, windows-7, uninstallation, language-packs

I’ve set up my computer with *Windows 7 Ultimate German* and *Visual Studio 2008 English*. Unfortunately I get now all messages of the .NET framework in German. This makes it difficult to search the web for error messages or to post a stack trace in an English forum.

How can I uninstall the German Language Pack in Windows 7? The .NET Framework seems to be part of the operating system and I can only uninstall it completely. The regular English setup of the .NET framework does not run in Windows 7.

I need the UI of my application to be in German and I want to get all messages that *are not visible to the end* user in English.

Comment: belongs on superuser, doesn't it?

Comment: doesn't - it is a programming task

Answer (score 0):

You can install the english language pack via Windows Update and change your user's language.
In Windows 7 every user can have a different language pack, I go for an english system + english visual studio.

I guess you write all messages for the UI of your applications by yourself.

Here is an article about english and german visual studio that might be interresting for you: [Heise.de Visual Studio auf Deutsch oder Englisch](http://www.heise.de/developer/Visual-Studio-auf-Deutsch-oder-auf-Englisch--/artikel/143299)

I prefer to write all the UI messages by myself (using ressource files) and have an english system to develop.